# JavaFX 8 ComboBox not showing items

Tags: java, javafx, combobox, scenebuilder

I am working on some academic JavaFX desktop application. While creating a signup form, I needed to use combobox / choicebox, but I have several problems in this step. The combobox isn't showing any items. I tried many fixes I found on Stack Overflow, but none of them seems to work. I'm sharing my main.java + controller codes aside with my FXML code.

**Main.java**

```java
package utilisateur.GUI.signup;

import javafx.application.Application;
import javafx.fxml.FXMLLoader;
import javafx.scene.Parent;
import javafx.scene.Scene;
import javafx.scene.control.ChoiceBox;
import javafx.stage.Stage;
import javafx.stage.StageStyle;

public class signupinterface extends Application {
    
    Parent signup;
    
    @Override
    public void start(Stage primaryStage) throws Exception {
        signup=FXMLLoader.load(getClass().getResource("signup.fxml"));
        primaryStage.initStyle(StageStyle.TRANSPARENT);
        Scene Signup_scene = new Scene(signup);
        primaryStage.setResizable(false);
        primaryStage.setTitle("Creation d'un compte");
        primaryStage.setScene(Signup_scene);
        primaryStage.show();
    }

    /**
     * @param args the command line arguments
     */
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        launch(args);
    }    
}
```

**Controller.java**

```java
package utilisateur.GUI.signup;

import java.net.URL;
import java.util.ArrayList;
import static java.util.Collections.list;
import java.util.List;
import java.util.ResourceBundle;
import javafx.fxml.Initializable;
import javafx.collections.FXCollections;
import javafx.collections.ObservableList;
import javafx.fxml.FXML;
import javafx.scene.control.ChoiceBox;
import javafx.scene.control.ComboBox;

/**
 * FXML Controller class
 *
 * @author malek
 */ 
public class SignupController implements Initializable{
    ObservableList list = FXCollections.observableArrayList();
@FXML
private ComboBox<String> signup_genre;

    /**
     * Initializes the controller class.
     */
    @Override
    public void initialize(URL url, ResourceBundle rb){

      signup_genre.getItems().addAll(
    "Option 4",
    "Option 5",
    "Option 6"
);
}

}
```

**FXML File**

```xml
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>

<?import com.gluonhq.charm.glisten.control.AppBar?>
<?import com.gluonhq.charm.glisten.control.BottomNavigation?>
<?import com.gluonhq.charm.glisten.control.ToggleButtonGroup?>
<?import javafx.scene.Cursor?>
<?import javafx.scene.control.Button?>
<?import javafx.scene.control.ComboBox?>
<?import javafx.scene.control.DatePicker?>
<?import javafx.scene.control.Label?>
<?import javafx.scene.control.PasswordField?>
<?import javafx.scene.control.TextField?>
<?import javafx.scene.image.Image?>
<?import javafx.scene.image.ImageView?>
<?import javafx.scene.layout.AnchorPane?>
<?import javafx.scene.layout.Pane?>
<?import javafx.scene.text.Font?>
<?import javafx.scene.text.Text?>

<AnchorPane minHeight="-Infinity" minWidth="-Infinity" prefHeight="576.0" prefWidth="657.0" xmlns="http://javafx.com/javafx/8.0.171" xmlns:fx="http://javafx.com/fxml/1" fx:controller="utilisateur.GUI.auth.AuthController">
   <children>
      <AppBar minHeight="-Infinity" prefHeight="55.0" prefWidth="657.0" spacing="45.0" style="-fx-background-color: #008080;" styleClass="-fx" titleText="" />
      <Button id="login" fx:id="auth_login" layoutX="349.0" layoutY="429.0" mnemonicParsing="false" onAction="#LoginButton" prefHeight="38.0" prefWidth="94.0" style="-fx-background-color: #008080; -fx-background-radius: 35px;" text="S'inscrire" textFill="WHITE">
         <cursor>
            <Cursor fx:constant="OPEN_HAND" />
         </cursor></Button>
      <Button id="auth_cancel" fx:id="auth_cancel" layoutX="460.0" layoutY="429.0" mnemonicParsing="false" onAction="#cancelButton" prefHeight="38.0" prefWidth="102.0" style="-fx-background-color: #008080; -fx-background-radius: 25px;" text="Annuler" textFill="WHITE">
         <cursor>
            <Cursor fx:constant="OPEN_HAND" />
         </cursor></Button>
      <ImageView fitHeight="65.0" fitWidth="74.0" layoutY="-5.0">
         <image>
            <Image url="@../resources/wazzup.png" />
         </image>
      </ImageView>
      <BottomNavigation layoutX="315.0" layoutY="12.0" />
      <Pane layoutX="-14.0" layoutY="-125.0" prefHeight="200.0" prefWidth="200.0">
         <children>
            <Text fill="WHITE" layoutX="84.0" layoutY="157.0" strokeType="OUTSIDE" strokeWidth="0.0" text="WAZZUP - Inscription">
               <font>
                  <Font name="Arial Rounded MT Bold" size="18.0" />
               </font>
            </Text>
         </children></Pane>
      <ToggleButtonGroup layoutX="449.0" layoutY="248.0" selectionType="SINGLE" />
      <ImageView fitHeight="528.0" fitWidth="440.0" layoutX="-49.0" layoutY="28.0">
         <image>
            <Image url="@../resources/wazzup.png" />
         </image>
      </ImageView>
      <ImageView fitHeight="94.0" fitWidth="102.0" layoutX="195.0" layoutY="476.0">
         <image>
            <Image url="@../resources/mindunits.png" />
         </image>
      </ImageView>
      <Label layoutX="86.0" layoutY="502.0" opacity="0.54" style="-fx-font-size: 15px;" text="Developpé par " textFill="#6161619e" />
      <Label id="auth_verif" fx:id="auth_verif" layoutX="358.0" layoutY="204.0" prefHeight="21.0" prefWidth="204.0" textFill="RED" />
      <Text fill="#0000005f" layoutX="360.0" layoutY="113.0" stroke="#fffdfd61" strokeType="OUTSIDE" strokeWidth="0.0" text="Inscription" wrappingWidth="187.72559686005116">
         <font>
            <Font name="Berlin Sans FB" size="18.0" />
         </font>
      </Text>
      <DatePicker id="auth_dateb" fx:id="auth_dateb" layoutX="358.0" layoutY="217.0" prefHeight="25.0" prefWidth="204.0" promptText="Date de naissance" stylesheets="@../auth/css/textfield.css" />
      <TextField id="auth_nom" layoutX="358.0" layoutY="141.0" prefHeight="25.0" prefWidth="204.0" promptText="Nom" stylesheets="@../auth/css/textfield.css" />
      <TextField id="auth_prenom" layoutX="358.0" layoutY="179.0" prefHeight="25.0" prefWidth="204.0" promptText="Prenom" stylesheets="@../auth/css/textfield.css" />
      <TextField id="auth_email" layoutX="357.0" layoutY="330.0" prefHeight="25.0" prefWidth="204.0" promptText="Email" stylesheets="@../auth/css/textfield.css" />
      <TextField layoutX="357.0" layoutY="256.0" prefHeight="25.0" prefWidth="204.0" promptText="Numero de telephone" stylesheets="@../auth/css/textfield.css" />
      <PasswordField layoutX="357.0" layoutY="382.0" prefHeight="25.0" prefWidth="204.0" promptText="Mot de passe" stylesheets="@../auth/css/textfield.css" />
      <ComboBox id="signup_genre" fx:id="signup_genre" layoutX="358.0" layoutY="292.0" prefHeight="25.0" prefWidth="204.0" visibleRowCount="3" />
      
      
   </children>
</AnchorPane>
```

[image: After running]

[image: Photo from scene builder]

Comment: Yea exactly thats my issue , i copied auth.fxml and renamed as signup.fxml to save some time but i forgot about that x) , my bad , thanks alot sir !

Answer (score 3):

The controller for your fxml is

```
AuthController

fx:controller="utilisateur.GUI.auth.AuthController"
```

That has nothing to do with the controller you supplied which is

```
SignupController

package utilisateur.GUI.signup;
public class SignupController . . .
```

Comment: Yea exactly thats my issue , i copied auth.fxml and renamed as signup.fxml to save some time but i forgot about that x) , my bad , thanks alot sir !